# MySql query to Azure SQL query failing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, azure

I am trying to move my web site to Azure, and so to rely on their SQL servers, while before I was using Apache/MySql.

I have some difficulties trying to convert the queries, as they do not work anymore.

The following works if i connect to the MySql db, but it fails if I change the connection to the Azure SQL.

> string(178) "SELECT * FROM schemedb.users WHERE CreatedBy=20 ORDER BY dateCreation Desc" string(177) "SELECT IdUsr FROM schemedb.userssettings WHERE User=20 ORDER BY Id Desc"

All connections to the Azure SQL server are correct, as a simpler query before these gets executed fine. But then I got stuck here.

The php error console says

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object in ...

To understand where the problem was I used var_dump on the queries, to see where they were failing, turns out that if I change them to:

> string(178) "SELECT * FROM schemedb.users ORDER BY dateCreation Desc" string(177) "SELECT IdUsr From schemedb.userssettings Order By Id Desc"

These queries are then valid, so I guess that the problem is the `where` clause then, but I have no clue of what's the problem.

-- EDIT

I've made some test, turns out that if I manually write the query, it works as expected.

What I mean is that the above mentioned query is build through several php custom methods like so:

> ." WHERE ".$this->buildWhere()." ORDER BY ". etc.

But if I type there `WHERE CreatedBy = 20`, then it works.

My best guess is that it is a format problem, since in SQL Azure the data type in the query must be of the same type of the one declared in the column.

However, I cant' understand what's wrong, since my custom method is writing the value vithout `'`, therefore as a number, not a string...

Comment: Can you try putting parentheses around the where clauses? E.g. `WHERE (1 = 1) AND (CreatedBy = 20)`.

Comment: Nope, I've tried but the problem persists..